# Cannon Printer in CUPS rastertoufr2 failed

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I've installed an Rasperry Pi with a standard Rasbian image. Now I want to use my printer with cups (Cannon MF3010 - connected via USB). I've installed ppd file in cups and place the filter file under /usr/lib/cups/filter. But when I am going to print the file it give an error

```
D [26/Jul/2020:13:45:37 +0100] [Job 37] execv failed: Exec format error
**D [26/Jul/2020:13:45:37 +0100] [Job 37] PID 2104 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertoufr2) stopped with status 108 (Exec format error)**
D [26/Jul/2020:13:45:37 +0100] [Job 37] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [26/Jul/2020:13:45:37 +0100] [Job 37] Loading USB quirks from \"/usr/share/cups/usb\".
D [26/Jul/2020:13:45:37 +0100] [Job 37] Loaded 172 quirks.
D [26/Jul/2020:13:45:37 +0100] [Job 37] Printing on printer with URI: usb://Canon/MF3010?serial=0154A0000256&interface=1
```

Comment: You installed 3rd party binaries that weren't compiled for the Pi's processor; unless that 3rd party offers them in the correct flavour (which they probably do not), you are out of luck.

Comment: Be more precise, "I've installed an Rasperry Pi with a standard Rasbian image." Specify the version!

Answer (score 1):

Cups should be available for raspbian . Use `apt`. And then activate it with
service command.
Looks like you are trying to execute a deb file or source for amd processor. Try ARM